# Keycloak loginless flow doesn't offer user password login for users without a registered security key

Tags: keycloak, webauthn, redhat-sso

[According to the documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/server_admin/index.html#setup-3), the loginless flow consists only of a single execution:

[image]

It states that:

> You can now add the required action WebAuthn Register Passwordless to
> a user, already known to Keycloak, to test this. The user with the
> required action configured will have to authenticate (with a
> username/password for example) and will then be prompted to register a
> security key to be used for loginless authentication

So with that configuration an existing user without a registered security key should be able to login with their user/password and then offered to register the security key.

However, given that our authentication flow only has a single step (WebAuthn Passwordless Authenticator) they are never asked for their user/pass, instead, they are only offered the security key login directly:

[image]

Press sign in:

[image]

How can we support loginless auth and user/password for users without a registered device?